# I'm trying to create a JavaScript code that gives a 15% discount if the sum values of selected dropdown options, radios and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that I'm trying to give a 15% discount to the user if a dropdown option was selected. I've tried inputting the discount into the sumvalues function but it returned a NaN. Here's the code.

```
function sumValues() {

    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("radio");

    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    var sum = 0;

    if (dropdown.value !== "0") {
        sum += parseInt(dropdown.value);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
        if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
            sum += parseInt(radioButtons[i].value);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total price of products and/or services selected:$ " + sum;
}

if (dropdown.val !== "0") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total price of discounted products and/or services selected:$ " + sum * 0.85;
}
```

I also tried creating a separate function for the discount but it never worked. I'm trying to figure out how to do this. This is the separate discount function.

```
function discount(result) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

    if (dropdown.val !== "0") {
        result *= 0.85;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total discounted price of products and/or services selected:$ " + sum;
}
```

Comment: `"..." + sum\*0.85;` - what is that backslash doing there? And you should probably wrap that part in a set of braces.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The backslash wasn't there, I'm not sure how it got there. I tried braces but it returned a NaN.

Comment: Your **sum** in discount function is not declared. I think it's not global too since you declared it in your ```sumValues()``` function.

Comment: No it's not global. That's the error I got when trying to run the discount function, "sum not defined".

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe for the edit. But it still says "sum is not defined" on the discounted sum in the sumvalues function. Do I have to use both the discount function and the modified sumvalues function?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! To define the discounted sum variable I had to include it in the sumvalues function by dropping the second last brace below the last statement.

function sumValues() {

```
     var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("radio");

   var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

    var sum = 0;

if (dropdown.value !== "0") {
    sum += parseInt(dropdown.value);

}

for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
    if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
        sum += parseInt(radioButtons[i].value);
    }

}

 for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(checkboxes[i].value);

}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total price of products and/or services selected:$ " + sum;

 if (dropdown.val !== "0") {
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total price of discounted products and/or services selected:$ " + sum * 0.85;
}
```

}